# oracle sql adding extra row

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

I have data like this

```
col1            col2                                col3        col3  
ABC COMPANY     OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd           $50.00     MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd           $200.00    MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd           $100.00    MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park  $20.00     MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park  $200.00    MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park  $1,000.00  MMO64606
```

I need output to be like

```
col1            col2                                col3        col3  
ABC COMPANY     OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd           $50.00     MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd           $200.00    MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd           $100.00    MMO64606
                OH, Akron - 3636 Copley Rd Total     $350.00    
ABC COMPANY     OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park  $20.00     MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park  $200.00    MMO64606
ABC COMPANY     OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park  $1,000.00  MMO64606
                OH, Beachwood - 23700 Commerce Park Total   $1,220.00
```

I have used rollup but its grouping I am getting more number of rows ,
please suggest any solution.

## EDIT

```
select col1, col2,col3,sum(nvl(detailtype,0))
  from tab
  where rownum<10
  group by
  rollup(col1, col2,col3)
```

I have tried this way my original query is

```
select col1, col2,col3
  from tab
  where rownum<10
```

this gives only 9 rows when i am running the above query i am getting 27 such rows but thats not expected

Comment: Please can you provide the query you've tried?

Comment: select col1, col2,col3,sum(nvl(detailtype,0)) from tab
where rownum<10
group by  rollup(col1, col2,col3)
; I have tried this way my original query is   select col1, col2,col3,from tab
where rownum<10; this gives only 9 rows when i am running the above query i am getting 27 such rows but thats not expected

Comment: When adding information to a question do not put it in a comment; instead, use the `edit` button (location just under the tags) to add the new information to the question itself so everyone can see it when they read the question. I've done it for you this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ROLLUP in oralce.

check "ROLLUP " in this link http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php
same example i am posting :

```
SELECT fact_1_id,
       fact_2_id,
       SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value
FROM   dimension_tab
GROUP BY ROLLUP (fact_1_id, fact_2_id)
ORDER BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id;

 FACT_1_ID  FACT_2_ID SALES_VALUE
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          1     4363.55
         1          2     4794.76
         1          3     4718.25
         1          4     5387.45
         1          5     5027.34
         1               24291.35
         2          1     5652.84
         2          2     4583.02
         2          3     5555.77
         2          4     5936.67
         2          5     4508.74
         2               26237.04
                         50528.39
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` with partial sums:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4 
from test 
union all
select null, col2, sum(col3), null 
from test
group by col2   
order by col2, col1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6300/1)

or use `cube` and `grouping_id`:

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) col3, col4
from test 
group by cube(col1, col2, col3, col4)
having grouping_id(col1, col2, col3, col4) in (0, 11)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6300/2)

---

Edit: in first query `union all` is correct, not `union`